# python dict, find value closest to x

Tags: python, python-3.x

say I have a dict like this :

```
d = {'a': 8.25, 'c': 2.87, 'b': 1.28, 'e': 12.49}
```

and I have a value

```
v = 3.19
```

I want to say something like :

```
x = "the key with the value CLOSEST to v"
```

Which would result in

```
x = 'c'
```

Any hints on how to approach this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [`min(iter, key=...)`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#min)

```
target = 3.19
key, value = min(dict.items(), key=lambda (_, v): abs(v - target))
```

Comment: Python 3. I think iteritems() got replaced by items(). Confirm?

Comment: @jason: Yep, 2's `.items()` was removed, and 2's `.iteritems()` was moved to `.items()`

Comment: Love the lamas – I mean lambdas. :)  This is great.  Thanks!

Comment: What if I want to get 'k' closest key_value pairs ?

Comment: @bot28 Use `heapq.nsmallest` instead of `min`

Comment: Getting invalid syntax with this, version 3.9.9

Comment: Yes, `lambda (_, v): abs(v - target)` is no longer legal syntax, you need to use `lambda v: abs(v[0] - target)` instead

Answer (score 2):

You can do this:

```
diff = float('inf')
for key,value in d.items():
    if diff > abs(v-value):
        diff = abs(v-value)
        x = key

print x
```

which gives `'c'`

You can also use `min` to do the job:

```
x = min(((key, abs(value-v)) for key,value in d.items()), key = lambda(k, v): v)[0]
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you want it to do if two values are equally far from the target, but if that's ever an issue, you could use something like this

```
min_diff = min(abs(v - target) for v in d.values())
closest_keys = [k for k, v in d.items() if abs(v - target) == min_diff]
```

Answer (score 1):

for python3, use this:

```
target = 3.19    
key, value = min(d.items(), key=lambda kv : abs(kv[1] - target))
```

if you just want the key of the value that's closest to target:

```
value = min(d.items(), key=lambda kv : abs(kv[1] - target))[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like the following:

```
d = {'a': 8.25, 'c': 2.87, 'b': 1.28, 'e': 12.49}
v,l = 3.19,float('inf')
for name,value in d.items():
    if abs(value-3.19) < l:
        l = value-3.19
        n = name
print n
```

Comment: This definitely doesn't justify a second loop... And why not `l = float('inf')`?

Comment: Thank you for your feedback! You're right this could be done more easily with a single loop or lambda. In addition l = float('inf') makes more sense.